# How to save a file with a custom name using Show-ListView function?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I want to save a file with a custom name while using Show-ListView function. Right now, when I am trying to save the file it is returning in this format **"report-2019-02-25_095656.csv"**.

This is the simple script I am running:

$item | Show-ListView -Title "Export Items" -Property `
@{ Name="Item Name"; Expression={$*.Name}},
@{ Name="Item ID"; Expression={$*.ID}}

I want to save the file as **"abc_items.csv"**. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to modify a file name out of the box.

**Export to CSV** is one of the export options available for ListView.

You will find it here:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Core/Platform/Internal/List View/Export/CSV`

Notice that file name is hardcoded in the script.

[image]

If you want your own file format you will have to modify this item or create your custom button.